# If $f$ is a $K$-lipschitz function, and if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then is $diam(f(A))\leq Kdiam(A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

$A$ being of form $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, A= [a,b]$. Would that be true? I have no idea if it's true, even less how to prove it. Or would there be a similar inequality?

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of a Lipschitz function. What is your definition?

Comment: If you plug in the definition of diameter of a set, you will see this is true.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $ \mathbb R$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R$ a $K$-lipschitz fuction.

For $x,y \in A$ we have $|x-y| \le diam(A)$, hence

$|f(x)-f(y)| \le K|x-y| \le K diam (A)$.

This gives $diam(f(A))\leq Kdiam(A)$